# Getting error when upgrading from Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights v3.1 to v4.0

Tags: c#, azure-functions, serilog

I have an Azure Function that uses Serilog to write to AppInsights with [Serilog AppInsights sink v3.1](https://github.com/serilog-contrib/serilog-sinks-applicationinsights/releases/tag/v3.1.0).

The code in `Startup.cs` looks like this

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(config)
            .CreateLogger();
```

and `appsettings.json`

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
    ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
        "Args": {
          "instrumentationKey": "...",
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Verbose",
          "telemetryConverter": "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
      }
    }
  ],
  ...
```

It can happily write application logs into AppInsights.

The latest Github [documentation](https://github.com/serilog-contrib/serilog-sinks-applicationinsights#telemetryconfigurationactive-is-deprecated-in-the-app-insights-sdk-for-net-core-what-do-i-do) mentioned the deprecation of telemetry configuration active and future removal support of **Instrumentation Key** therefore I would like to upgrade the library to version 4.0.

However, when I upgrade to the sink to v4.0, I get this exception:

[image]

Please help.

Comment: What is the dotnet version you're using in the project?

Comment: Net 6.0, Azure function version v4

Comment: Could you try with this code and see if it resolves the issue: 


Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(
        serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<TelemetryConfiguration>(),
 TelemetryConverter.Traces)
    .CreateLogger();

Comment: Now it's showing a different exception.
------------
System.InvalidOperationException: 'No service for type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration' has been registered.'
------------
Besides, is there a declarative way rather than using .WriteTo() method.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

So I just spent a good chunk of time debugging this, because I also ran into the issue.  I'll admit I should have look at the git log for the app insights sink, because the offending commit is right here

https://github.com/serilog-contrib/serilog-sinks-applicationinsights/commit/8e4e26a8fdfa12da6ed15afcc94889e5f399ff97#diff-bc9f0e00aaa0aef88484faa764a62f13d26f07bf6c2b6df21cd8d893aa47c2e0

They adjusted their namespaces, which causes the Serilog Configuration binding not to be able to find the type `Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter` anymore.  Instead the namespace is `Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter` as shown in the commit I linked.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much @DarrienSingleton, the shortened namespace really helps.

In addition, I had to change the **Args** sections with connection string instead of instrumentationKey.

`"Args": {
    "connectionString": "...",
    "telemetryConverter": "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
}`

Comment: Would have been nice if they mentioned that in the breaking changes.